# Builduser() Error building user of type

Tags: macos, single-user

I have entered Single user mode like 5min ago. Meanwhile I shut down the computer, tried to get back to Single user mode my pressing `cmd+S` and it doesnt work. It outputs the error saying `Builduser() Error building user of type 0xffsomethinggoeshere`

It worked 5min ago. All I did was to run some ls commands. What could be the problem?

Edit> Verbose mode doesnt work either.

Comment: Have you restored /var or reinstalled the OS - or still got malware - from your previous answers your machine is in a non working state so until you do one or more of the above you are lucky to get it to do anything

Comment: Nope, just ls-ing the folders and seeing what was there. It turns out that that .Trashes is not the folder I should inspect. It is /Users/YOUR-USER-NAME/.Trash. This is where I will find /var

Comment: Basically I'm with @mark here. Your system is in an unknown state after removal of /var, so all bets are off regarding any error/warning messages you are getting.

Comment: I agree with you two. What bothers me is that it worked 5min ago, but now it wont.

Comment: You were lucky 5 mins ago - it is not a useful thing to bother about

Comment: So how to make a dics copy? I cant login, and I cant run from single user mode.

Comment: Boot into recovery mode and take it from there